# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' Error

Tags: python

I am getting this error after a function returns a list of Str and Int, and I assign it to a variable. 
Code being:

```
    for line in allpersons:
        tempperson = line.split(',')
        ...
        ...
        personhouseholditems = LookupHouseholdID(personhousehold)
```

LookupHouseholdID being:

```
def LookupHouseholdID(personhousehold):
        householdslist = households.readlines()
        for line in householdslist:  
            temphouse = line.split(',')
            if temphouse[0] == personhousehold:
                x = temphouse[4]
                y = temphouse[5]
                z = Referencez(temphouse[7])
                k = Referencek(temphouse[12])
                if temphouse[13] == '':
                    a = '"N/A"'
                else:
                    a = Referencea(temphouse[13])
                personhouseholdlist = [x, y, z, k, a]
                return personhouseholdlist
```

(omitting names for reasons)

The error I get specifically is:

```
    newpersons.write("    <attrib key='x' value=" + str(personhouseholditems[0])  + " />" + "\n" + "\n")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

If I print personhouseholditems I get this:

```
[x, y, z, k, a]
None
```

Comment: The variable `households` in `householdslist = households.readlines()` does not exist yet.

Comment: it does, I defined it earlier I just forgot to add it to the code, all of the variables that I readlines from are defined at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You did not ask a question.

If you want to know what the error means then it is saying that you are trying to call **getitem** on an object of type NoneType, which doesn't have **getitem** defined. The NoneType object is the personhouseholditems, and **getitem** is the [0] part trying to get its first element.

If your question is "help me debug my code", then either post your whole code, or better yet, try to write a minimal example script which also causes that error.

I think that when you actually try that, you will be able to find the bug in your code yourself. Most likely it will be because your function does not return a list in every branch, only if you go to the for cycle and if you go to the if part)

Answer (score 0):

Adding typing and using a type checker (i.e. `mypy`) will help you avoid this type of bug.  If I add typing to your function to match your description of it (it returns a list of strings and integers):

```
from typing import List, Union

def LookupHouseholdID(personhousehold: str) -> List[Union[int, str]]:  # mypy error!
    ...

person_household_items = LookupHouseholdID(person_household)
print(person_household_items[0])
```

then when I run `mypy testfile.py`, it prints out an error telling me what the bug is:

```
Missing return statement
```

which is exactly correct; your function does not always return a value, but you said it would always return a `List[Union[int, str]]`.

If I change the annotation to say that it doesn't need to return a value (the return is Optional), then I can fix the "missing return" by just adding a `return None` to the end:

```
from typing import List, Optional, Union

def LookupHouseholdID(personhousehold: str) -> Optional[List[Union[int, str]]]:
    ...
    return None

person_household_items = LookupHouseholdID(person_household)
print(person_household_items[0])  # mypy error!
```

Now I get an error when I try to take `[0]` of `person_household_items`.  That's because it's `Optional`, which means that it can sometimes be `None`.  You can't safely do anything to an `Optional` value that you can't do to a `None` value:

```
Value of type "Optional[List[int, str]]" is not indexable
```

And this is the exact error that you're hitting at runtime -- your function returns `None` and you try to index it with `[0]`.

So to fix it, you'll need to either make sure your function always returns a non-empty list, or you'll need your other code to account for the case where your function didn't return anything.  For example:

```
person_household_items = LookupHouseholdID(person_household)
if person_household_items is not None:
    print(person_household_items[0])  # no error, because we checked that it's not None!
else:
    print("no items!")
```

For more information about mypy: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/